# asp.net core3.0 webapi request.body and [frombody] conflict

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webapi

I need to get the body through `request.body` after frombody, but I haven't found a solution after testing for 2 days. I've added `Request.EnableBuffering()`.

```cs
// PUT: api/Test/5
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<string> PutAsync(int id, [FromBody]ProductInfo value)
{
    var ccccc = "";
    Request.EnableBuffering();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, encoding: System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        ccccc = body;
        Request.Body.Position = 0;
    }
    return ccccc;
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: please provide ProductInfo definition as well and explain what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 4):

I believe the issue you are having is your `cccc` comes back empty. This is likely because by the time you entered your controller, the request body stream has already been read through. It makes sense - something has to populate the `value` parameter for you. So it is too late to try and rewind the stream at this stage.

[ASP.NET Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/re-reading-asp-net-core-request-bodies-with-enablebuffering/) has an article on how you would approach this: you need a custom middleware and you need to insert it into the pipeline above MVC middleware.

#### Startup.cs

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<CustomMiddleware>(); // register your custom middleware with DI container
    services.AddControllers();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseMiddleware<CustomMiddleware>(); // inject your middleware before MVC injects theirs

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

then your custom middleware might look like so:

#### CustomMiddleware.cs

```cs
public class CustomMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        context.Request.EnableBuffering(); // now you can do it

        // Leave the body open so the next middleware can read it.
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body, encoding: Encoding.UTF8, detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: false, leaveOpen: true))
        {
            var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            context.Items.Add("body", body); // there are ways to pass data from middleware to controllers downstream. this is one. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46601757/c-sharp-dotnet-core-2-pass-data-from-middleware-filter-to-controller-method for more

            // Reset the request body stream position so the next middleware can read it
            context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
        }

        // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
        await next(context);
    }
}
```

and finally in your controller, you will fetch the body from `context` like so:

```cs
// PUT: api/Test/5
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<string> PutAsync(int id, [FromBody]ProductInfo value)
{            
    var ccccc = (string)HttpContext.Items["body"];
    return ccccc;
}
```

this method comes with a few caveats, that are discussed in the article. watch out for huge request bodies and tune your buffer size accordingly.