# Throwing custom exceptions on JSON type mismatches ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

What I am attempting to do is throw my own exceptions when there is a type mismatch between the `JsonTokenType` and the `object/struct` I am converting to.

For example, my object is LoginRequest:

```
public class LoginRequest
{
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

And my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateCredentialsAsync([FromBody] LoginRequest request)
{
    // Do Stuff
}
```

But if a user provides an integer instead of a string (or really any type mismatch) for the username/password I want to serve a custom exception.

For example imagine the client calls my server with the following JSON body:

```js
POST {ip}/api/login
content-type: application/json
{
    "username": 123,
    "password": "password"
}
```

now from an `IAsyncActionFilter` I can read the `ModelState` and see it is invalid, but I don't see a way to differentiate error causes and throw different exceptions.

What I would like to do is throw a `CustomBadRequestException(errorCode: 3, message: "Really, you think that should be a number and not a string")`, but if they fail to provide the username at all I want to throw `DifferentCustomBadRequestException(errorCode: 2, message: "Nice try hacker")`

Do I need a custom model binder in order to do this (or even extend an existing model binder), or do I need some sort of deserialization setting and/or converter that can provide more specific exceptions based on what went wrong, or both?

Bonus question: Is it possible to collect all the errors in the model state before the action filter is called (this sound like it would absolutely require a custom model binder but I figured I would ask)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm fully across your problem statement, but assuming you want more control over model deserialisation, some tweaks can be made to MVC json serialiser options:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc(o => { })
                .AddJsonOptions(s =>
                {
                    s.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new Converter()); // one way to gain more control will be to use custom converter for your type, see implementation down below
                    //if you are after something a bit more simple, setting behaviours and handling general error events might work too
                    s.SerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error; // you probably want that so your missing 
                    s.SerializerSettings.Error = delegate(object sender, ErrorEventArgs args)
                    {
                        // throw your custom exceptions here
                        var message = args.ErrorContext.Error.Message;
                        args.ErrorContext.Handled = false;
                    };
                });
        }
```

implementing Converter is fairly easy:

```cs
    class Converter : JsonConverter<LoginRequest>
    {
        public override bool CanWrite => false;

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, LoginRequest value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override LoginRequest ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, LoginRequest existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            // your logic here
        }
    }
```

---

**UPD** after getting a better view of your specific requirement re handling primitive types it seems trying to fiddle with MVC serialiser gets a bit too cumbersome. Reason being, the level of control you're after (especially checking primitive types ) seems to be available on `JsonTextReader` level, but it seems overriding that would mean reimplementing a significant chunk of library code:

```cs
services.AddMvc(o =>
            {
                o.InputFormatters.RemoveType<JsonInputFormatter>();
                o.InputFormatters.Add(new MyJsonInputFormatter(logger, serializerSettings, charPool, objectPoolProvider));// there are quite a few parameters that you need to source from somewhere before instantiating your formatter. 
            })
....
class MyJsonInputFormatter: JsonInputFormatter {
    public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(
      InputFormatterContext context,
      Encoding encoding)
    {
        ...your whole implementation here...
    }
}
```

Therefore I think the most viable approach would be injecting custom middleware before MVC and doing something along the lines of [schema validation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonSchema.htm) for your raw json. Since MVC **will** need to re-read your json again (for model binding etc), you would want to check out my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59598589/asp-net-core3-0-webapi-request-body-and-frombody-conflict/59605982) that caters for request steam rewinding.

Comment: I agree the converter for this specific type would be easy, but the issue is this needs to be a common check for all types across my system. Anytime a user POSTs a JSON body with an int when it should be a string should throw the same error, or anytime a user POSTs a JSON body with a bool instead of an int, etc.

Comment: okay, I think I understand your problem statement better now. to double check - you want to check whether deserialised type matches the target member type?

Comment: Yes, to make sure the deserialized type matches the target member type.